# Cloud Run - Allowing users to deploy a single resource, based on permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-iam

I'm almost having an headache while trying to allow access on GCP Cloud Run for different users, for a specific service using permission attributes.

Let's consider I have different services running, and I want to assign my developers to use `gcloud run deploy` only on a bunch of them. In my case, this is like as following:

- backend-service > revisions can be deployed by backend-user only;
- frontend-service > revisions can be deployed by frontend-user only;

Both users have "Cloud Run Developer" role, and both services account have the "ServiceAccountUser" role as described [here in GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/iam/roles#additional-configuration)

The issue I'm facing however is when I try to restrict user permissions for a single resource.
Using the GCP web console, I've created a condition based on `Resource > Name` to be `backend-service`.

I instantly get this error when using `gcloud run deploy`:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'run.services.update' denied on resource 'namespaces/PROJECT_ID/services/SERVICE_NAME' (or resource may not exist).
make: *** [deploy] Error 1
```

As I could not find anything related to IAM permission conditions related to Cloud Run [(they're not even listed afaik)](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview) I tried changing the `Resource > Name` condition value to `namespaces/PROJECT_ID/services/SERVICE_NAME`, but that didn't work too.

As a side note, when checking permissions inside Cloud Run Web Console it shows
**Condition on Cloud Run Developer**

```
{
    "expression": "resource.name == \"backend-service\"",
    "title": "BackendService"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cloud Run doesn't support IAM conditions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview#resources). You have several workarounds

- Wait for an update
- Create different projects
- Automate the deployment (only the CI/CD pipeline can deploy, not directly the users)
- Add permissions at the resource level and not at the project level.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! However, isn't adding permissions by `resource.name` actually adding permission at resource level?

Comment: you can add a binding between a role and a resource (and thus create a policy). When you add a condition, you add to the policy biding a condition of enforcement. It's not exactly the same thing. For Cloud Run you can create a binding at service (resource) level but you can't set IAM condition on the service name

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I tried your 4th method: I used an Owner user A to create & deploy a Cloud Run (CR) service R, then add user B with CR Developer role to R's permission. But when I tried on another PC to deploy new revision of R (using `gcloud run deploy --source . --project projectP` with user B cred):

`ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) User [B] does not have permission to access projects instance [projectP] (or it may not exist): Permission 'run.locations.list' denied on resource 'projects/projectP' (or resource may not exist).`

Could you help to check if I am doing something wrong here?

Comment: Can you try to deploy a container instead of deploying source (replace `--source` by `--image`)? And let me know the result